# Sanitize JSON output from DynamoDB

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have this script from the AWS docs:

```
<script>
  AWS.config.update({
    region: "us-east-2",
    endpoint: 'https://dynamodb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com',
    // accessKeyId default can be used while using the downloadable version of DynamoDB. 
    // For security reasons, do not store AWS Credentials in your files. Use Amazon Cognito instead.
    accessKeyId: "myfakeid",
    // secretAccessKey default can be used while using the downloadable version of DynamoDB. 
    // For security reasons, do not store AWS Credentials in your files. Use Amazon Cognito instead.
    secretAccessKey: "myfakekey"
  });

  var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

  function readItem() {
    var table = "CONNECT_STATUS";
    var CGW_ID = "FF00000001";
    var CON_ID = "EE00000001";

    var params = {
      TableName: "MyTable",
      Key: {
        "CGW_ID": CGW_ID,
        "CON_ID": CON_ID
      },
      "ProjectionExpression": "Curr"
    };

    docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML = "Unable to read item: " + "\n" + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2);
      } else {
        document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2) + " Amps";
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

And the following HTML:

```
<input class="refresh "id="readItem" type="image" src="img/refresh.png" onclick="readItem();" />
<br><br>
<textarea readonly id="textarea" style="width: 150px; height: 50px"></textarea>
```

The trouble I am having is that when the output is returned, it is returned in JSON format with the curly brackets and the word "Item". Is it possible to extract only the value of the column named "Curr" without any curly brackets or text or inverted commas? Only the value.

Also, is it possible to run calculations on the value of "Curr" either in the frontend or will it require something else?

I am new to DynamoDB and learning. I greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML = data.Item.Curr + " Amps";
```

also:

```
// Convert the `Curr` numeric string to a number.
var curr = Number(data.Item.Curr);
```

Comment: That worked exactly how I wanted it to work! Thank you @Khalid T.